# I don't understand the last output for this block of code

Tags: c++

Well, this code was taken from a practice exam for a programming thing that i'm very under qualified for, but i'd still like to know the reason behind the output for this.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    char g = 'X', t = '1', *k_ = &t;

    g = 'y';
    cout << *k_ << *k_ << endl;
    g = 'Y';
    cout << *k_;
    k_ = &g;
    t = 'Z';
    cout << *k_ << *k_ << *k_ << endl;

    return 0;

    }
```

I don't understand why the output for the last cout is 1YYY if there are only three k_ pointers, and there's that 1 that's bothering me too.

Comment: Count the `*k` after the `cout`s. There are 6 of them, so you should see 6 characters.

Comment: Yeah, I should have noticed that too, but it was the lack of the endline statement after the second cout that tricked me.

Comment: there is no `endl` after the second `cout << *k_;`, hence all the 4 *k_ are couted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char g = 'X', t = '1', *k_ = &t;

g = 'y';
cout << *k_ << *k_ << endl; // prints out 11 with a newline
g = 'Y';
cout << *k_; // prints out 1 without a newline, so next cout will be on the same line
k_ = &g; // k_ now holds g's address (remember g is now 'Y')
t = 'Z';
cout << *k_ << *k_ << *k_ << endl; // prints out YYY on the same line as 1 from above

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Whoa, this helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The previous cout doesn't have a new line output.  That one prints the '1' that k_ pointed to originally.

Comment: Yes. I agree that it was a bit sneaky. And I am finding that answering these on an iPod touch is a painful process.

Answer (score 3):

```
1. cout << *k_;
2. k_ = &g;
3. t = 'Z';
4. cout << *k_ << *k_ << *k_ << endl;
```

There is no endl at the end of or after line 1. So the `1` you're seeing is from that line.

Answer (score 2):

There's one output of the old `*k_` (1) without a newline, then three after `k_` is set to `&g` (by now 'Y').

Answer (score 2):

It isn't just the *last* `cout` that contributes to outputting `1YYY`, it's the one before it too:

`cout << *k_;`
 outputs `1` and then after `k_ = &g;`
 which sets `k_` to point to `g`, `cout << *k_ << *k_ << *k_ << endl;` outputs `YYY`.

Each `cout` *does not by break a line by default*, which is what I presume you've been thinking. You need to explicitly pass `endl` or `"\n"` to break a line.

Comment: Oh man, I feel really stupid for not noticing that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake: you thought of the ';' at the end of the cout instruction as a newline. Just notice that the unobfuscated code is finally equivalent to:

```
    cout << '1' << '1' << endl << '1' << 'Y' << 'Y' << 'Y' << endl;
```

or leaving out the noise ends in pseudo output:

```
    1 1 endl 1 Y Y Y endl
```

and printed in the terminal device (which moves the cursor at endl):

```
11
1YYY
```

Hint: A debugger program allows you to walk line-by-line through your code and monitor the terminal output in parallel.